# how to play in earpiece speaker on Android with libpd

Tags: android, puredata, libpd

I use AudioParameters.suggestOutputChannels() by PdAudio.initAudio(). The suggested output channel is 2 and the result is the phone speaker goes on.

**How to turn on the phone earpiece speaker by libpd in Android?**

The AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL returns 0, but then I do  PdAudio.initAudio() with 0 as output channel there is no sound at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found that there is no straight solution:
The libpd contains class AudioWrapper, which creates

```
track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sampleRate, channelConfig,
 ENCODING, trackSizeBytes, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

so where is no direct way to overwrite AudioManager.**STREAM_MUSIC** to AudioManager.**STREAM_VOICE_CALL**.